# import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts'; NOT WORKING

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, chart.js

I am trying to use chart.js in my Ionic 3 project, but it generates an error when I import ChartsModule in my "app.module.ts" . I am getting this error

Object(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_aangular_core))[« defineInjectable »])is not a function…

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yE1c.png)

...

```
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [ MyApp ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(FIREBASE_CONFIG),
        AngularFireAuthModule,
        AngularFireDatabaseModule,
        ChartsModule
    ],
```

...

This is my "package. json" file code below :
This is my "package. json" file code below :
This is my "package. json" file code below :

```
{
  "name": "Beep",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.13",
    "@angular/core": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.3",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.5-next",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "cordova-android": "7.1.4",
    "cordova-ios": "4.5.5",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.7",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "firebase": "^4.9.1",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.2.2",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.3",
    "@ionic/lab": "1.0.18",
    "typescript": "2.4.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you installed the dependency it using `npm install ng2-charts chart.js` ? How does your package.json look?

Comment: Yes I installed them (I am not sure whether they are installed correctly or not, I don't know how to check that). Here is my package.json file : https://wetransfer.com/downloads/330fc5076047f59d1ec828c963e4d76820190417191049/ab726a4697ca34a4047606eba899b44320190417191049/851a81

Comment: You can check your `node_modules` to see if there is a directory for ng2-chart. Also please post the package.json as code in your question.

Comment: Yes, they exist in node_modules

Comment: OOps, your error says: `Promise error. Invalid Link, createTocPage` . This is not the problem with installation or import. Check your routing and links in the app.

Comment: I just made an error in the image (sorry), now I updated the post with the correct image

Comment: looks like some issue with `ThemeService` and it's usage.. please post your service and how it is used.. It's very difficult to tell anything by seeing a screenshot of error

Comment: this is the link for the code : https://github.com/SofianeMeziani/AppToc

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please make sure to add a minimal verifiable code snippet for others to take a look and understand your problem. For more details on how to create [mcve] check this.